# Images showing large in Internet Explorer on Magento Website

Tags: internet-explorer, magento

I have a webpage that shows correctly in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer. The website was made in Magento. Here is the address: _store=default">http://www.rwprotect.com/testing-data/?_store=default

Any ideas on how to make it show correctly in IE?

Thank you!!

Comment: I opened this hoping that `Magneto Website` wasn't a typo...

Comment: @admdrew - I know, I viewed it out of intrigue too.  I have amended the typo in the header for you :).  user2953232 what version of IE are you talking about?  There are many.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean with "shows not correctly in Internet Explorer"? I've used IE9 and there are a lot of very big images, which aren't so big in Chrome. It's also not a magento question, just a regular html/css layout problem I guess.

First I would clean up your code for the images. In your `<img>`-tags you're setting a fixed with and height, but it will be overridden by css rules from your external css files.

I guess IE is not interpet these css rules correctly (max-width? procent?) or has a priority problem. Unfortunately the build-in developer tool is not helpful and doesn't even show the image in the DOM structure ^^

[image]

You can also play with `!important`, but use it sparingly. It forced the highest priority if multiple css rules belongs to the element:

```
img{height:auto !important; }
```